# Spark DF create Seq column in witcolumn

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a df:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abcdefghi |
| 2 | qwertyuio |

and I want to repeat each row, dividing the col2 in 3 substrings of lenght 3:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abcdefghi |
| 1 | abc |
| 1 | def |
| 1 | ghi |
| 2 | qwertyuio |
| 2 | qwe |
| 2 | rty |
| 2 | uio |

I was trying to create a new column of `Seq` containng `Seq((col("col1"), substring(col("col2"),0,3))...)` :

```
    val df1 = df.withColumn("col3", Seq(
(col("col1"), substring(col("col2"),0,3)),
(col("col1"), substring(col("col2"),3,3)),
(col("col1"), substring(col("col2"),6,3)) ))
```

My idea was to select that new column, and reduce it, getting one final Seq. Then pass it to DF and append it to the initial df.

I am getting an error in the withColumn like:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Spark array function instead:

```
val df1 = df.union(
    df.select(
        $"col1",
        explode(array(
            substring(col("col2"),0,3),
            substring(col("col2"),3,3),
            substring(col("col2"),6,3)
       )).as("col2")
    )
)

df1.show
+----+---------+
|col1|     col2|
+----+---------+
|   1|abcdefghi|
|   2|qwertyuio|
|   1|      abc|
|   1|      cde|
|   1|      fgh|
|   2|      qwe|
|   2|      ert|
|   2|      yui|
+----+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use udf also,

```
val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq((1L,"abcdefghi"), (2L,"qwertyuio"))).toDF("col1","col2")
df.show(false)
// input
+----+---------+
|col1|col2     |
+----+---------+
|1   |abcdefghi|
|2   |qwertyuio|
+----+---------+
 
// udf
val getSeq = udf((col2: String) => col2.split("(?<=\\G...)"))
df.withColumn("col2", explode(getSeq($"col2")))
  .union(df).show(false)

+----+---------+
|col1|col2     |
+----+---------+
|1   |abc      |
|1   |ghi      |
|1   |abcdefghi|
|1   |def      |
|2   |qwe      |
|2   |rty      |
|2   |uio      |
|2   |qwertyuio|
+----+---------+
```